# change a web page template by another web page using cookies

Tags: php, javascript, html, templates, cookies

I have two web pages `admin.php` and `user.php`. `admin.php` has control over `user.php`.
I have 4 controls(buttons) in `admin.php` that 2 of them are for changing the template(appearence) of `admin.php` and work fine (I did it using cookie).

2 other controls(buttons) are for changing the template for `user.php`.
But I don't know how to achieve this?
Should I pass the cookies from `admin.php` to `user.php`? If so, how should I pass them? Or maybe I should use JavaScript?

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: If your two pages are set on the same domain, then you shouldn't have any trouble sharing cookies between the two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your two pages are set on the same domain, then you shouldn't have any trouble sharing cookies between the two.

You just have to make sure you specify the correct domain. Use an absolute path instead of a relative one.

ex:

```
name=newvalue; expires=date; path=/; domain=.mydomain.org
```

Suggestion:

Since you're using php, why not using it to specify the template? Since it's a user  configuration, you probably want it to last regardless of the user clearing the cookies.